# como diseñar un formulario con animación que se despliegue asi abajo en la barra del buscador!

Tags: html5, bootstrap, login

Quiero diseñar un formulario que se despliegue hacia abajo, que formulario o fremework me recomienda para diseñar el mio. quiero utilizar bootstrap pero no se como aplicarle a animación por así decirlo para cuando coloque el mouse en el icono o boton se me desplace el login hacia abajo, gracias de ante mano!

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con Collapse de Bootstrap.  Documentacion aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La animación la puedes realizar con CSS puro [usando `@keyframes` y la propiedad `animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). Todo lo que tienes que hacer con Javascript es añadir la clase que tiene configurada la animación. Ejecuta el ejemplo para ver como funciona:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#box').addClass('show');
});

$('#reset').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#box').removeClass('show');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hidden {
  margin-top: -120px;
}

@keyframes SlideDown {
  from {
    margin-top: -120px;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.show {
  animation: SlideDown 1s ease-in;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Mostrar</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<div class="parent">
  <div id="box" class="hidden">
    <p>Contenido aquí</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Otro contenido</p>
```

Comment: si tengo un slider debajo del mi boton por que cuando le doy clic se baja mi slider y muestra un espacio prudencial  para motrar el contenido , como puedo hacer para que este por  encima del slider

Comment: Si lo que quieres es esconder el contenido de atrás en lugar de desplazarlo, puedes  cambiarle al elemento padre el css `position:absolute`. Actualice el ejemplo con eso.

Comment: pero en mi contenido el boton queda como inactivo cuando  paso la position:relative  a absolute.

Comment: @merwilvegas uhmm tal vez ese contenedor padre está encima del botón y no deja hacerle click? Chequea con el inspector y crea otra pregunta con un ejemplo si no logras resolverlo.

Comment: ya pude resolver una parte tuve q cambiar muchas cosas ! pero ahora tengo otro problema